# Класс настроек и конфигурации

Tags: ооп, php

Как более красиво и правильно реализовать класс для хранения настроек приложения (php, MVC)?
Какой паттерн при этом лучше использовать (Singleton или др.)?

Answer (score 3):

Настройки для программы должны быть одни. Это не будет запутывать и будет верным решением. Также, эти настройки должны быть доступны желательно из одного места - класса, обернутого в Singleton. Поэтому, самое правильное решение было бы использование паттерна Одиночки.

Этот паттерн, собственно, для этого и предназначался. Даже во время разннообразных уроков, где показывают реализацию Singleton`а в качестве примера берут именно класс с настройками.

Comment: Мне просто очень не нравится "одиночка", стараюсь избегать :)
Спасибо :)

Comment: Странно, что вы избегаете одиночки! Данный паттерн хоть и самый легкий в реализации, но и полезный. Избегать его не следует хотя бы потому, что иначе один экземпляр класса вам не создать.

Comment: Я вот тоже всегда стараюсь его избегать

Comment: Странно, ведь он не несет с собой особой "опасности", в отличие от других, более сложных паттернов.

----
И кстати, если вы реализуете одиночный класс с данными не через синглтон, то скажите как, может ваш способ правда лучше.

Comment: Ну например как вам проблема изменения настроек в рантайме? (не единственная проблема).
Пытаюсь избегать и не использую, к сожалению, разные вещи. В этом случае нет панацеи. Просто вы так сказали как будто этот паттерн не приносит никаких проблем.

ps можете закидать камнями, но я даже больше предпочитаю делегаты)

Comment: Ну любой паттерн несет проблемы, даже Фасад. Только серьезность проблем зависит от конкретной реализации.

Comment: Непонятно причем тут фасад... ну да ладно.

Просто я действительно не вижу для себя особого применения синглтона

Comment: @Asen, говорит бред, и чую не разбирается в паттентах, настойки обернуть в синглтон это полный бред.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, у вас уже реализован синглтон Приложения?

Приложение может хранить настройки в качестве одного из своих свойств как объект или ассоциативный массив. При инициализации Приложения читать настройки из ini файла, или из БД, как Вы реализовали.

Comment: Я на самом деле не уточнил, настроек много(для модулей/плагинов и прочее и прочее), я их беру из разных yml/json. Реализован как статический класс.

Comment: Это же самый настоящий быдлокод!
 
      может хранить настройки ... как ассоциативный массив

Comment: @Asen, зависит только от быдловатости кодящего. Амазон, например, в своём PHP SDK именно в виде ассоциативных массивов работает с наборами ключей:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=CFCredentials/set
Чистота да порядок.

Comment: @Asen, и что же в этом плохого?

Comment: @Asen ну хотя пару слов о том почему плохо

Comment: Ну как известно, класс - это новый тип данных со сложным поведением, в отличии от примитивных типов (массивов, например). Так, в классе, содержащем настройки (обернутого в синглтон) вам может понадобиться обновить какой-то элемент настройки приложения. Это будет сделать легко и в будущем вы не запутаетесь в нем, если у вас именно класс (опять же обернутый синглтон), а не массив. Для массива, где хранятся настройки, вам придется писать уйму функций, взаимодействующих с этими настройками. Вывод: получится быдлокод =)

Comment: А чем легче менять в классе это значение? Оповещать опять же надо будет всех кто им пользуется, такая же уйма методов (причем в дальнейшем, не понятно кого еще надо будет оповещать об изменениях)

Comment: Класс один, в том то и дело...ведь это синглтон. Все, кто будут пользоваться данным классом даже не заметят, что он изменился - они будут просто брать из класса опр. информацию.

Comment: @Asen а если уже взяли? Надо оповещать 

По вашей логики из массива также можно взять новое значение

Comment: А вот для этого и надо работать с классом и его методами **напрямую**!

Comment: О_О где мой комментарий? Еще раз спрошу @Asen, а в чем будет различие от обращения напрямую к элементам массива?

Comment: Вырвал всех одиночек и все сделал на много приятнее через DI. Хранить настройки в массиве лично мне эстетически неприятно :) Это идеологически неверно (в рамках ООП) :)